# Web API upload to a storage service stream request bytes

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to create a Web API controller to post a file to a storage service like Azure storage for example. The web api client is an AngularJS web page. The issue now is the progress bar on the file upload is showing 100% without sending any bytes to the backend storage service. I did turn off the buffering on uploads. Is there a way send the bytes to the backend storage as we receive them from the web api client? Is this possible with HttpClient in .NET 4.5?

Comment: I did it with ngUpload

Comment: My question is more how to pass through bytes from the web api to the backend, not on the client side.

Comment: The WebApi runs server side. What you are saying makes no sense.

Comment: I know it is, you are saying you did it with ngUpload, this just your client side implementation using AngularJS isn't it? I am asking how to pass through the stream from the original request to a second request for the storage service without buffering it and be able to send it byte by byte, so the client side progress is accurate going to the storage service and not just the web api.

Comment: This question has no answer...